# Размер файла не меняется после удаления базы

Tags: delphi, sql

Удаляет всю базу, база формата mdb (Access), но размер файла не изменяется. Почему?

```
begin
try
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM db');
   ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM db');
   ADOQuery1.Active:=True;
except
   on e:Exception do

  end;
```

Comment: @Skaynet, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, надо выполнить сжатие базы. СУБД обычно увеличивают файл данных при добавлении записей, но не сжимают при удалении (да и зачем - все равно разрастется). Так что сжатие файла данных - обычная обслуживающая процедура на совести админа или планировщика заданий .